# Getting a list of all active messages in a CAN Bus

Tags: can-bus, capl

I'm just learning to use `CAPL` on `CANoe` and I need to create a gateway that filters messages between 2 CAN Buses.

For the first part I need to create a way to toggle the transmission from Bus 1 to Bus 2 and vice versa (already done).

Then I have to be able to select a specific message from any of the buses to send it over to the other bus. All of this must be don graphically with a panel and I'm using checkboxes for the toggle of part 1 and dropdown lists for the message filter.

Do you know of a way to get a list of the active (Rx/Tx) messages in a bus from the last, say, 10 seconds? (I know I must use a timer to call the update function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to all messages from a bus by defining an `on message` event handler. It will be called for each message (subject to the filter condition you have specified). You can create a gateway by retransmitting messages using `output`.

For example, your graphical panel can set a variable `my_id` to the ID of a message you want to relay from bus 1 to bus 2. You could then write:

```
on message CAN1.*
{
   message CAN2.* msg;
   if((this.dir == rx) && (this.id == my_id)) {
       msg = this;
       output(msg);
   }
}
```

The additional condition `this.dir == rx` is necessary if you want to relay the same message from bus 1 to bus 2 and vice versa. It will prevent you from retransmitting the same message indefinitely.